# Keep Basic Authorization Alive in HttpURLConnection using API (Java)

Tags: java, inputstream, httpurlconnection, basic-authentication

I am retrieving data through an API using HTTP Basic Authentication in the following way:

```
        for (int i = 1; i < 10000; i++) {
            try {
                URL newurl = new URL ("SOMEURL" + i + ".json");
                HttpURLConnection newconnection = (HttpURLConnection) newurl.openConnection();
                newconnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                newconnection.setDoInput(true);
                newconnection.setRequestProperty ("Authorization", "Basic " + encoding);
                try {
                    InputStream newcontent = (InputStream)newconnection.getInputStream();
                    BufferedReader bfReader = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (newcontent));          
                    String newline;

                    if ((newline = bfReader.readLine()) != null) {
                        out.println(newline); 
                    }
                }
                catch(Exception e2) {
                }
            }
            catch(Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Question: Instead of asking for authentication 10,000 times, can I get the authentication once for the first request, keep it alive, and make the remaining 9999 requests without asking for authentication?

Purpose: Faster processing, less load on the server.

Any comments?

Answer (score 0):

HTTP is designed to be stateless, so there is nothing wrong with your approach. However, you can (but not recommened with an API) you sessions (with cookies) or provide a login URL which will issue a temporary auth token which you can pass.